# javascript cyrillic regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate cyrillic and regular alphabet? encoded urls, this is my curren regex:

```
if (/^((http|https):\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i.test(url)) {
    return true;    
}
```

I need to validate urls like: http://stackoverflow.com and http://правительство.рф/
Any Ideas?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? can you post a url that you need validating ?

Comment: Hi, i need to validate urls like: http://stackoverflow.com and http://правительство.рф/

Answer (score 4):

You can simply add `а-я` to your character classes:

```
if (/^((http|https):\/\/)?[a-zа-я0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-zа-я0-9]+)*\.[a-zа-я]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/i.test(url)) {
```

Comment: @greenbandit: I need more information. First, visit the above-linked jsFiddle, and look in the lower-right part. What do you see?

Comment: I've copied above and fiddle one and for some reason not works, is very frustating!

Comment: Works with my previous one, but when I change for your code validate still validate latin urls

Comment: @greenbandit: Re: "when I change for your code validate still validate latin urls": I don't understand. You've said repeatedly that you *do* want `http://stackoverflow.com` to be considered valid. Is that not the case?

Comment: I mean, validate latin urls but not cyrillic, BTW im using jquery to pass the url from a input box, maybe I need to do different way? another regex? [^\u0000-\u0080] this regex validate cyrillic but no latin.

Comment: @greenbandit: I'm sorry, but I'm not understanding what you want. Can you give two examples of URLs that *are* valid, and two examples of URLs that are *not* valid?

Comment: the valid urls are from main question.

Comment: @greenbandit: Then when you say that this regex doesn't work for you -- can you give an example of a URL that *is* valid, that this regex does *not* accept, or a URL that is *not* valid, that this regex *does* accept?

Comment: @greenbandit: Please visit [the above-linked jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XW7vN/2/), and look in the lower-right part. What do you see? *I* see that the Latin and Cyrillic URLs are both marked as valid. Do you see something different?

Comment: first and second are ok, third not.
I've tryied this code and validate cyrillic but not latin:
[^\u0000-\u0080]

Comment: @greenbandit: Re: "first and second are ok, third not": Good. So this regex *does* work for you. The problem must be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: any ideas? Im just passing text from an input, no server side, I cant find the solution!, this regex works for cyrillic only: http://jsfiddle.net/9Xxn8/

Comment: @greenbandit: If you can create a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue, I'll take a look.

Comment: This is my full validate function: http://jsfiddle.net/YeTey/ as you see, nothing unusual.

Comment: @greenbandit: Can you post a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9055/discussion-between-greenbandit-and-ruakh)